# python web scraping, submit data and get output

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have this website for search data (http://wedge3.hcauditor.org),
This is an image on the start page.

[image]

#### example Inputs-

here first input box(`House # Range`) = `3419`

and the `second one` is   (empty)

and third one(`Street Name`) = `Wabash`

when we submit this data and we have this link,
http://wedge3.hcauditor.org/view/re/0570005018800/2017/summary

we can't create URL for searching data because of only change in this link Parcel ID(0570005018800)

actually, I am new to the python web scrape, but I have good knowledge of urllib, beautifulsoup and requests modules.

I need to know, can we do this with python and if it is which module use for this.

I am using python 3.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use selenium. Simple example below -

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Chrome("./chromedriver") #download chromebrowser
browser.get("http://wedge3.hcauditor.org/") #open page in browser
outDF = pd.DataFrame(columns=['prodname', 'imageurl', 'minprice', 'maxprice', 'actualprice']) #template of data
browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[contains(@name, 'site_house_number_low')]").send_keys('3419')
browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[contains(@name, 'site_street_name')]").send_keys('Wabash')
x = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@type, 'submit')]/span")[1].click()

#browser.quit()
```

You will have to download chromedriver for this

Comment: thank you Aritesh, this is what, I am exactly expected. thank you very much.